# Clicked div's ID value to SQL select

Tags: javascript, php

I have displayed table using sql Select.

And in top pf page I have different clickable div's .

```
<div class="cities">
        <div id="all" class="all city">
            All
        </div>
        <div id="one" class="one city">
            ONE
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="two city">
            TWO
        </div>
        <div id="three" class="three city">
            three
        </div>       
    </div>
```

And after them is info table with sql like:

```
            <div class="all">
            <?php 
global $wpdb;
$resi = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
    p.ID as order_id,                 
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'additional_' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as city,
  
FROM
    wp_posts p 
    join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim on oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
    join wp_wc_order_stats oimi on pm.post_id = oimi.order_id
WHERE
    post_type = 'shop_order' AND
    oim.meta_key = '_qty'
group by
    p.ID DESC
    ");

$i = 1;
echo '<table id="customers"><tr>';
echo '<th>ID order</th>';    
echo '<th>City</th>';
echo '</tr>';

foreach( $resi as $key => $res ){
    echo '<tr id="'.$i.'">'; 
    echo '<td class="row-data">' . $res->city. '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

And now I wanna do what on div One will show all results but if u click like on two or three when in sql WHERE appears WHERE pm.meta_key = 'additional_' = CLICKEDdivID,

Sorry my english bad but maybe will understand. Waiting for help, thanks

Comment: Remember that your SQL is being handled in PHP, on your server.  In order to change the query, your HTML has to send a request to the server.  You can do that using a `<form>`, or you can make an AJAX request, but you have a lot of work to do.  Why do you think your `<div>`s are clickable?

Comment: In start i was did like this but don't know if this is good, i was write in all diffs same sql seletect but with one  if(city==all) and etc. 

and make this      $("#one.city").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();    
            $(".all").toggleClass('active');
            $(".all.two").toggleClass('active');
        });

Comment: That should manage the active/inactive state of the divs.  It won't send anything to the server.